# Codeigniter redirect after login to a Rule page before home page

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

How to redirect after login to a "Rule Page" on which user needs to agree the rules thats stated before heading to home. If disagree, logged out.

I managed to load the Rule page but my rule page is in content part so its loading the rule page and the whole header menu too. 
When user clicked on the header menu, they are redirected to another page without to agree on the rules.

Controller : user.php

inside the controller class:

```
protected function ensureRulesPassed() {
if ((int)$this->input->cookie('rules-gate') !== 1)
                redirect("user/page/rules");}


function login(){
$POST["id"]=strtoupper(trim($this->db->escape_str($_POST["id"])));
        if(!isset($_POST["id"]) || empty($_POST["id"]) || !isset($_POST["pw"]) || empty($_POST["pw"])) exit("Please complete all fields!");
        $r=$this->mylib->user_login(strtoupper($_POST["id"]), base64_encode(md5($_POST["pw"])));
$this->ensureRulesPassed();
}
```

Controller :rules.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Rules extends CI_Controller {
  public function index() {
$this->load->view('user/page/rules');
```

}

```
  public function accept() {
$cookie = array(
  'name'   => 'rules-gate',
  'value'  => 1,
  'expire' => '86500',
  'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
  'path'   => '/'
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
exit('Logging in..<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">location.href="'.site_url("user/page/how-to-play").'";</script>');
```

}

result: it keeps loading some-domain.com/user.

folder path
view: user/rules

View: rules.php

```
        <form >
            <fieldset>
                <legend><h2>Rules</h2></legend>
                <?php echo $r["ticker_descr"];; ?>
            </fieldset>

<a href="<?php echo site_url("rules/accept"); ?>">  <div class="medium primary btn" style="float:right;"><input type="button" value="Agree" name="submit1" /></div></a>

<a href="<?php echo site_url("user/logout"); ?>"><div class="medium primary btn" style="float:left;"><input type="button" value="Not Agree" name="submit2" /></div></a>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a method on your controller that checks if a cookie is set for the rules-gate:

```
protected function ensureRulesPassed() {
    if ((int)$this->input->cookie('rules-gate') !== 1)
         redirect(base_url('/rules'));
}
```

In the constructor for your controller call `$this->ensureRulesPassed();`

This is the important part:

Create a NEW controller for the rules page, this is so that the rules controller has a new constructor and isn't calling the `ensureRulesPassed()` method (because this would create a redirect loop)

Then you have to set the 'rules-gate' cookie from a get confirmation request on the rules controller:

```
class Rules extends CI_Controller {
  public function index() {
    $this->load->view('rules');
  }

  public function accept() {
    $cookie = array(
      'name'   => 'rules-gate',
      'value'  => 1,
      'expire' => '86500',
      'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
      'path'   => '/'
    );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    redirect(base_url());
}
```

N.B. the 'accept' button on the rules view should point to `/rules/accept`  if you were wondering.

Comment: Hi. I tried your idea but no success. When I put the function in the function login, but it keeps loading the user page. I updated the code in my question. could u please look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a good idea to separate the header menu from the views you want to load for the rule page.

I usually create a head.php file which contains the ... and a header.php file which contains the menu.

and then you just dont load the header file.

You can then force the user to agree to the rules by using a session boolean variable. if it is false and the user tries to access a page without agreeing, you could redirect them back to the rule page with an error message for example.